# Сруктура БД, хранение свойств

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть список пользователей хранятся в отдельной таблице. Пользователей около 800000, нужно дать возможность админу сайта, добавлять новые свойства для пользователей.

Не знаю как правильнее это организовать, с бы в дальнейшем не было проблем, со скоростью работы,выборки данных и т.д.

Планирую создать отдельную таблицу для свойств. В котором будут поля, тип свойства, название, значение и `UserID` - которая будет привязкой к пользователю.  Если пользователь не ввел значение в какое то из созданных свойств, то нет смысла держать его в бд. Т.е. в таблице будут для каждого пользователя разное количество свойств.

Подскажите это нормально? Чем это чревато и какие есть другие решения,  Лучше?

Ведь записей в это таблице максимум будет в `N` раз больше чем пользователей, где `N` - количество свойств.

Comment: В реляционных БД именно так и делается. Это нормально (от термина "нормальная форма"). Правда есть избыточность. Названия свойств и тип, если свойство с одним названием можно задать нескольким пользователям, лучше хранить в третьей таблице. А в таблице свойств буквально UserID, СвойствоID, значение

Comment: Это нормально, почитайте о нормализации БД, тогда всё поймете.

Comment: В первом приближении - либо разреженная таблица атрибутов, либо EAV. Первое хуже тем, что требует DDL при формировании новых атрибутов, зато позволяет фиксировать тип атрибута и "ословарить" его с поддержанием целостности.

Comment: @Mike преобразуйте комментарий в ответ.